# Unable to extract property with SQL JSON_QUERY

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have the folowing Json data stored in a sql table :

`{"OrderNumber":"12450-OF","OrderType":"OF"}`

I need to extract the OrderNumber from a sql query

The folowing statement returns `null`:

```
select 
   JSON_QUERY(Metadata,'$.OrderNumber') AS 'orderNumber'
from Documents
```

where `Documents` is my table, and `metadata` is the column where my json data is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `JSON_VALUE()` to extract a scalar value from a JSON content.   `JSON_QUERY()` is usually used to extract an object or an array from a JSON string.

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(Metadata,'$.OrderNumber') AS 'orderNumber'
FROM (VALUES
   ('{"OrderNumber":"12450-OF","OrderType":"OF"}')
) Documents (Metadata)
```

Note, that if you want to extract more values from the stored JSON, `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema is another option:

```
SELECT *
FROM Documents d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.Metadata, '$') WITH (
   OrderNumber varchar(10) '$.OrderNumber',
   OrderType varchar(2) '$.OrderType'
) j
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace function Json_Query to JSON_VALUE.

```
JSON_VALUE use for getting value from json.
JSON_Query use for getting object from json string.
```

For example, if you have:

```
"OrderNumber":["12450-OF","12450-02"]
```

then your query will return object

```
["12450-OF","12450-02"]
```